# How to merge formatted and unformatted cells while keeping the formatting of the formatted cell to apply to the merged cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

How to horizontally merge formatted and unformatted cells from 2 columns while keeping the formatting of whichever formatted cell to apply to the merged cell?

So far, I've done it manually in 4 steps:

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

**Step 4:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

How to automate the process with a formula?

Comment: Record a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't really a formula for that (best you could have would be to merge it but without formatting). Maybe you should try keyboard shortcuts especially this combo:

- select range
- press <kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- press <kbd>M</kbd>
- press <kbd>H</kbd>
- press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

then you could use [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for example and map this key combo to some key and invoke it with a single press

Comment: Thanks a lot for those shortcuts! That's a great time saver! How do you find about those shortcuts M and H? I just researched the ALT + O one and found it is for the Format menu here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en  I see the logic behind some  (M= Merge in the menu, H= Horizontal in the sub-menu) but how do you know about it for general purposes with the menus? Do you simply take the 1st letter of the first word of each selection of menu/submenu? I'll test it!

Comment: Interesting this autohotkeys program. Will test it also!

Comment: after you press alt+o you can see that in each selection there is one letter which is underlined - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSFt8.png - that's your shortcut key